# I am asked to take oath forcefully by my wife repeatedly

Tags: quran, nikah, sharia, sin, sunnah

I am interested in a woman and I am married. My wife found out about our relationship now she daily force me to take oath on Quran while I don't want to . I am not in a happy relation with my wife but live with her for the sake of my kids . Kindly tell if I take oath forcefully is it valid.

Comment: As of my understanding, taking an oath when you know it is not valid is a lie. Be honest to your wife. Or clear, at least. Your question looks like seeking forgiveness in advance.

Comment: In christian folklore the hand that was used for a false oath is said to grow out of the grave and show itself above, as the blessed earth of the graveyard will not contain such a sin.

Answer (score 0):

Such oath is not valid especially in this regard !!!.

A wife can not forcefully stop nor compel her husband not to marry another. Neither do you need her consent to do so. Allah has already granted you that.

The General Principle here is, an oath or promise taken to accomplish or to perpetuate something haram, whilst contradicting an established halal, is null and void!!!!

If you have already done that, simply make istihara (repentance), go ahead and do what is needful and put your trust in Allah....